# URL for an image in the Assets directory of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, routes, assets

I need the public facing url of an image in my `app/assets/images` directory.

On development, I can navigate to the image by hitting `localhost:3000/assets/image.jpg`.

However, when I push this app to heroku, that url no longer works.

I can't visit `my_app.com/assets/image.jpg` or I get a routing error saying `"No route matches get assets/image.jpg."`

How can I navigate to that URL? I am not really interested in helper methods to generate the URL, I just need the full length url.

Comment: have you compiled assets on heroku? or run your localhost in production mode and check is it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you including the `rails_12factor` gem in production? This will do a number of things for you, including set `config.serve_static_assets` to true which is false by default in production.